# fatal error: esp_nimble_hci.h: No such file or directory on Ubuntu command line with idf V4.4

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bluetooth, esp32

I am trying to compile my project on Ubuntu, with idf V4.4 installed. When I run idf.py I get the following error message:

```
main/ble.c:12:10: fatal error: esp_nimble_hci.h: No such file or directory
#include "esp_nimble_hci.h"
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[1049/1070] Building C object esp- 
idf/wifi_provisioning/CMakeFiles/__idf_wifi_provisioning.dir/src/scheme_softap.c.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja failed with exit code 1
```

I have compiled the same project in Windows in Espressifide and it compiles fine, but when I try to on Ubuntu on the command line it fails.

Why would it not find the BT component? Its enabled in my sdkconfig file.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's because I'm running "idf.py set-target esp32s3" before running "idf.py build".
If I just run the build command then it builds successfully. For some reason setting the target messes up with the sdkconfig.

I could tell this was the case because if I run "idf.py menuconfig" my sdkconfig gets reset, I then have to restore my changes and open it again before it loads my actual sdkconfig.